# How to solve error HRESULT: 0x6d HTTP 500 substatus 1013 when Deployed in Azure with Node.js Express and IISnode?

Tags: node.js, angular, express, iis, iisnode

I keep on getting an error in my app for when I try to POST from a contacting form. Here's the kicker, it worked (to received email) on my dev environment with localhost. And it even worked receiving email when I deploy it to a vm Windows Server from my host desktop. But it **does not** work when I deploy it on Azure Windows Server, both of my vm server and Azure have the same setting in IIS with node.js and IISnode installed.
Sort of new to the whole node.js/express and IISnode development, any help to get it working and resolved would be much appreciated.

[error screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WrXX.png)

web.config

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
        </handlers>
        <!-- <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough"> -->
        <iisnode nodeProcessCommandLine="C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" logDirectory="C:\inetpub\logs\abc\iisnode" loggingEnabled="true" />
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
            <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
        </modules>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="abc_test">
                    <match url="api/*" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

server.js

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3003`
const app = require('./app')
app.listen(PORT, function(){
     `console.log("Server Listening On Port: ", PORT);
})
```

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));`
app.use(cors({origin: "*"}));
const generalRoutes = require('./api/route/general');
app.use('/'+'abc_backend/api/general/', generalRoutes);
module.exports = app;
```

general.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const gController = require('../controller/generalController');
router.post('/contacting', gController.sendingMail);
module.exports = router;
```

generalController.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const app = express();
const sendingMail = async(req, res) => {
 let user = req.body;
 let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 host: "smtp.gmail.com",
 port: 465,
 secure: true, // true for 465, false for other ports
 auth: {
  user: "aasome.fakemailzz@gmail.com",
  pass: "somefakepass"
 }
});
let mailOptions = {
 from: "contact@somefakedomain.io",
 to: "fakename@somefakedomain.com",
 subject: "New Contact Message",
 html: <b>Name: </b> ${user.userName} <br>
 <b>Email: </b> ${user.email} <br>
 <b>Phone: </b> ${user.address.postalCode} <br>
 <b>Message: </b> ${user.address.city}
};
let info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
 res.send(info);
}
module.exports = {
 sendingMail
}
```

contacting.service.ts

```
export class ContactingService {
 public url:string;
 constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {
  this.url = environment.backendAPIurl + "/general/";
 }
 contactSubmit(userName: string, email: string, postalCode: string, city: string){
  const bodyData = {
   userName:userName,
   email: email,
   address:{
    postalCode:postalCode,
    city: city
   }
  }
  return this._http.post<any>(this.url +"contacting",bodyData);
 }
}
```

Comment: Don't use iisnode, as it is out of maintenance. Switch to Linux if you can. If Windows must be used, use HttpPlatformHandler for your NodeJS app.

Comment: try to use the code structure like this : `const apiAi = require("apiai");

module.exports = function(app, server) {
   const apiAiApp = apiAi(Constants.API_AI_ACCESS_TOKEN);
   
   //Now, do something with apiAiApp
}`

Answer (score 0):

Got it resolved. Took a look at the error log after enabling IIS_USr to write the log to the directory in the web.config. The error indicates its a Google authentication thing, on production server Google won't work if the incoming request server is not secure/SSL.

Also found a stackoverflow link that mentioned same concept. [iisnode encountered an error when processing the request. HRESULT: 0x6d HTTP status: 500 HTTP subStatus: 1013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48940207/iisnode-encountered-an-error-when-processing-the-request-hresult-0x6d-http-sta)

Solved by clicking on this link and sign on with the account from nodemailer.createTransport({})  to allow it. https://accounts.google.com/b/0/DisplayUnlockCaptcha